# File transfer on Raspberry Pi using pscp

Tags: linux, windows, raspberry-pi2, qemu, pscp

I am trying to send file from windows local system to QEMU raspberry pi emulator.But every time I am getting "access denied".I have downloded **pscp.exe**.
I have tried the following commands:

```
pscp.exe -scp myfile.txt pi@192.168.1.3:/home/pi

pscp.exe -scp myfile.txt pi@192.168.1.3:~/home/pi

pscp.exe -scp myfile.txt pi@192.168.1.3:~/Desktop

pscp.exe -scp myfile.txt pi@192.168.1.3:~
```

Every time it's giving Access Denied.Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Close to something you want to achieve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106012/how-to-access-raspberry-pi-qemu-vm-via-network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am probably late, but anyway this may help someone.

The syntax of pscp is

`pscp [options] source [user@]host:target`

Target is the destination **file** and you are inputting a folder. Also, you are using a *file syntax* `/home/pi` and not a *folder syntax* `/home/pi/` (note the `/` **slash** at the end). So you are asking pscp to overwrite your entire user folder and put the source file instead. Needless to say this could have result in a massive catastrophe, deleting your entire home folder.

Your command should be:

`pspc myfile.txt pi@192.168.1.3:/home/pi/myfile.txt`

You can even hard code your password so that the transfer occurs without prompting.

`pspc -pw yourpassword myfile.txt pi@192.168.1.3:/home/pi/myfile.txt`